Is 'I had got my hair dyed' correct?
As in British English, they use the "Have got" construction. I wonder if using the 'got' plus the 'had' for the causative is possible just like the simple present tense.

have got is not British English only. In the past perfect, however, it's got/gotten for BrE/AmE.

Yes, you can speak of 'getting your hair dyed' (having someone do it for you), so you can say "I had got my hair dyed" (though "I had had my hair dyed" would be more usual).

Thank you very much!

My mother said that only vulgar women had their hair dyed; she had hers coloured.

@MichaelHarvey that is a very odd thing to say ... why does she think that dyed is in the vulgar realm?

@jsotola - a British 'class' thing. Like saying 'scent', not 'perfume'. She was born in 1920.
